# how can i change the pretrib and postrib characters in \attrib?

Tags: formatting, captions

I wish attributions to be of the form
-- 
rather than
()

The author has something of the sort on his TODO list, but the release date of \attrib is AD1999 -- 22 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can renew the commands using `\renewcommand`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attrib}
\renewcommand{\PreTrib}{{-}{-}}
\renewcommand{\PostTrib}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{quotation}
Better to reign in Hell, then serve in Heav'n.
\attrib{\textit{Paradise Lost}}
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I thank you, kind sir!  Works perfectly.  I am in your debt.

Comment: @russ The way to say thank you to answers on this site is to click the uparrow to the left of the answer, if it has value.  If you get multiple answers to your question, protocol is to consider them all and, for the one that best or fully answers your question, click the check mark to the left of that answer to "accept" it (only one accepted answer per question).  This will tell other readers what worked best for your circumstance and is the way to say "thank you" to those who took the time to help you.  Welcome to the site.